# Converting inputted string to list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

In my application user inputs data which is then used in calculating.

For example, the inputted data is:

[[74, 74], [65, 73], [91, 69]]

And of course, when trying to print(type(data)) I get string type.

I iterate through these arrays so I need it to be list type.

I tried using split/eval, yet no success

```
#Enter text_to_decipher
  print("Enter your text to decipher or keep the default: ")
  print(text_to_decipher)
  print('\n')

  #start collecting input
  temp_text = ""
  while True:
    temp=input()
    if temp == "":
      break
    else:
      temp_text = temp_text + temp 

  if temp_text != "":
      text_to_decipher = temp_text
  print (text_to_decipher)
  print (type(text_to_decipher))

  text_to_decipher = input()
  print (type(text_to_decipher))
```

Error that happens when my code tries to iterate through the string and not the list:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 1091, i <module ats1=iter(pair,k[2],iter_function) file "main.py", line 1022, in iter r=M[1] IndexError: string index out of range`

Any ideas?

Comment: dont lnk your error message to an external site, it's not that long to just cop/paste: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 1091, i
     <module ats1=iter(pair,k[2],iter_function)   file "main.py", line
     1022, in iter r=M[1] IndexError: string index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

str_data = '[[74, 74], [65, 73], [91, 69]]'
data = ast.literal_eval(str_data)
print(type(data), data)
# <class 'list'> [[74, 74], [65, 73], [91, 69]]
```

Comment: Does it change any values when literal_eval is used?
Because yes, it converts to a list but I think it changes something in the inside of the list because I am getting 
`

»»´¿
    »   ½´°
½¼º        ·º§¤ª«
¯­½¥»k»¬½»¬ºª§«´½§¸²¿·` as my decrypted message. Something should be off with int/string values

Comment: Changed a few values and your solution works. Thanks a lot.